# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() when adding ROLE during registration in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, roles

I am trying to add default ROLE upon registration of the user. I add `->assignRole()` but it gives me this error

[image]

here's my create function

```
use App\HasRoles;

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ])->assignRole('borrower');

    $user_id = $user->id;

    // HasRoles::create([
    //     'role_id' => 4,
    //     'user_id' => $users->id,
    // ]);

    Referral::find($data['referral_id'])->update ([
        'status'    => 1,
        'date_used' => $data['referral_date_used']
    ]);

    CollectorMember::create ([
        'collector_id' => $data['referral_generate_by'],
        'borrower_id'  => $user_id,
        'referral_id'  => $data['referral_id'],
    ]);
    return $user;
}
```

you'll also notice the commented hasRole::create. well I thought that's just like that.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe if you add the `assignRole()` after create the user, it works. First create the user, and, in the next line, add the role to the user:
`$user->assignRole('borrower');`

Comment: Glad to help you. I added it as answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `assignRole()` method after create the user.

```php
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
$user->assignRole('borrower');
```